# How to define queue time variables in Azure DevOps YAML

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Azure DevOps is now warning that all variables which may be settable at the time of queueing must be declared in the pipeline as settable at queue time. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/inputs?view=azure-devops#queue-time-variables) shows how to do that with the Pipeline UI editor. However, there is no explanation how it is done in the YAML source file.

Hence the question: How to define queue time variables in Azure DevOps YAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In YAML you can achieve it using runtime parameters instead of variable

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script

Answer (score 2):

> How to define queue time variables in Azure DevOps YAML?

You can define the queue time variable in YAML Pipeline Variable UI page instead of YAML code.

[image]

Then you can define the variables in **Variables** option and enable the option: **Let users override this value when running this pipeline**

For example:

[image]

In this case, you can modify the variable at queue time.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am reusing the same pipeline YAML file in many projects, I need a method which does not require unnecessary GUI interaction when creating the pipeline.

Luckily, it is possible and the second link in the answer of Kontekst describes this. For convenience, I am providing an example here as well. The following

```
parameters:
- name: BuildType
  displayName: Build type
  type: string
  default: development
  values:
  - experimental
  - development
  - release
```

When starting the pipeline from the DevOps GUI, the above definitions will cause that the variable display name ("Build type") is displayed with a bullet selection where the value can be chosen. The `default` (in this case "development") will be selected initially.

If the pipeline if started automatically (a commit trigger), then the defined variables will have their default values.

The value of parameters is accessed in the pipeline like normal pipeline variables, i.e. in this case by `$(BuildType)`.